# The target _RemoteBuild does not exist

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to build Xamarin iOS project from the Windows machine using the following command:

```
msbuild ProjectiOS.csproj /t:_RemoteBuild /p:ServerAddress=IP.ADD.RESS.HERE;BSAT=BSAT
/p:Configuration=Ad-Hoc /p:Platform=iPhone
```

As per instructions [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3696/how-to-build-from-msbuild-command-line-trig-build-on-osx-from-windows).
But receiving "The target _RemoteBuild does not exist in the project" all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking at outdated forum-based instructions (for XVS 3.x). Once you have paired your Windows machine to your Mac Remote Build Host all you have to do from Windows is:

```
msbuild Solution.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=AppStore;Platform=iPhone
```

The ServerAddress, BSAT options, etc.. were dropped in the XVS 4.x+ version when Xamarin went to a single secure port (22) connection to the Mac Build Host.

If you need to connect to a non-paired build host:

```
msbuild Solution.sln /p:ServerAddress=10.1.10.100 /p:ServerUser=MyUserID /p:Platform=iPhone /p:ServerPassword=MyMacPassword
```

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/

### Command Line Support

> The new agent also supports building a Xamarin.iOS configuration from the command line. To use it, you will need to pass the following required parameters to MSBuild:
>
> PARAMETER NAME DESCRIPTION
>
> ServerAddress  The IP address of the Mac server.
>
> ServerUser The Username (not Full Name) to be used to log in to the Mac Server.
>
> ServerPassword (optional)  The Password used to log in to the Mac host.
>   The ServerPassword parameter is not required.
>
> Instead, the first time a password has been passed, either by using Visual Studio or the Command Line, for that particular Windows, Mac, and user configuration a key pair will be generated and stored on the Windows machine for future use.
>
> It will be located in %localappdata%\Xamarin\MonoTouch\id_rsa. **If you do not pass the ServerPassword parameter, the id_rsa keyfile will be used for authenticating**.
>
> An example command to connect to Mac 10.211.55.2 using xamUser account with password ‘mypassword’ is shown below:

```
C:\samples\App1>msbuild App1.sln /p:ServerAddress=10.211.55.2 /p:ServerUser=xamUser /p:Platform=iPhoneSimulator /p:ServerPassword=mypassword
```

Comment: But it still needs to be connected to Mac though, right? How do remote creds should be specified?

Comment: Once you go through the pairing process once you do not have to do it again (unless the machines change of course)

Comment: Do you mean paring using IDE? So.. I can run the script above right after I paired a Mac machine using Visual Studio for example, right?

Comment: I updated the answer with the host/uid/passwd options